# redirect of https://www.example.com to https://example.com not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, elastic-beanstalk

I am using elasticbeanstalk to redirect HTTP requests to a secure port.

I want to redirect all my requests to `https://example.com`.

The following scenarios are working

- `http://www.example.com` --> `https://example.com`
- `http://example.com` --> `https://example.com`

However,

- `https://www.example.com` --> doesn't work and it redirects to `https://www.example.com`

I am using the following Rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

I took the help of the following article to understand the use case
https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/

As per my understanding, the following condition should work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per my understanding, the following condition should work
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
> ```

Yes, this "works". However, your first *condition*:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
> ```

ensures the directive is only processed for HTTP requests.

If you are using *Elastic Beanstalk*, then I don't believe you should be checking `%{HTTPS}` anyway (at least you don't *need* to) - since it will always be `off`. You can resolve your issue by removing this redundant check and moving the `OR` flag to the first condition. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

(*Aside:* You need to be careful when checking both `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` and `%{HTTPS}` as this could enable someone to bypass your redirect if not served from behind a proxy. If you are not serving your content from behind a proxy then you should not be checking `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}`.)